# How to separate a date in c programming c date functions

Tags: c, string, date, pointers

Write a function GetDate with the following prototype:
void GetDate (char * date, int * dp, int * mp, int * yp);

Function accepts a string parameter and date showing date as follows:
dd - mmm - yy

two digits to mark the day, three-letter shortcut to mark the month and year in two digits. The function is to separate the components and deliver them by reference to a numerical format. An example of running the program that calls the function
Enter a date as

```
dd-mmm-yy:
28-Aug-63



Day = 28
Month = 8
Year = 63
```

the code i make and isn't working is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning (disable:4996)


void GetDate(char *date, int *dp, int *mp, int *yp);

void main()
{
    char date[9];
    int dp, mp, yp;

    printf("Enter a date as dd-mmm-yy:");

    GetDate(date, &dp, &mp, &yp);


    printf("day=%d\n", dp);
    printf("Month=%s\n", &mp);
    printf("Year=%d\n",yp);
}

void GetDate(char *date, int *dp, int *mp, int *yp)
{
    char *mon[] = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
    char date[9];
    int i,dp, yp,size=sizeof(mon)/sizeof(mon[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        mon[i]=i+1
    }
    gets(date);
    sscanf(date, "%d-%s-%d", &dp, mp, &yp);


}
```

Comment: `char date[9];` is too short for the string `"28-Aug-63"`. You need a extra byte for the `'\0'` terminator.

Answer (score 1):

sscanf gets pointers as argument to receive the data from the string , since dp and dy are already pointers, you should not extract their addresses with another & signs .

second all , you pass date as argument, then override it with a local "date" variable. you should not declare another date inside the function .

also, sscanf is a very non safe function , try to validate the string before you pass it to sscanf with your own validation function

finally , I don't get what your loop is doing inside the function , but you have an array of pointer to character . you try to assign there some integer as value , with is nor valid memory address nor a valid string

Answer (score 1):

Code has key problems with:

```
char date[9];
...
gets(date);
sscanf(date, "%d-%s-%d", &dp, mp, &yp);
```

`char date[9]` is too small.  Do not try to severely limit user input.  Let's use twice the expected size: `char date[2*(9+1)]`

Rather than `gets(date)` - which is obsolete, use `fgets()`.

Do not scan using simply `"%s"` as `mp` will be "Aug-63" and not the hoped for `"Aug"`.  Use `"%3s"`

Return a status indicated success/failure.

```
int GetDate(char *date, size_t size, int *dp, int *mp, int *yp) {
  static const char *mon[] = { 
      "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
      "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

  int i;
  int monsize = sizeof(mon)/sizeof(mon[0]);
  char input_mon[3+1];

  if (fgets(date, size, stdin) == NULL) {
    return 1; // fail: EOF or IO error
  }
  if (3 != sscanf(date, "%d -%3s -%d", &dp, input_mon, &yp)) {
    return 1; // fail: input not formatted properly
  }
  for (i = 0; i < monsize; i++) {
    if (strcmp(input_mon, mon[i]) == 0) {
      *mp = i + 1;
      break;
    } 
  }
  if (i == monsize) {
    return 1; // fail: No such month
  }
  return 0;
}

void main(void) {
  char date[2*10];
  ...
  if (GetDate(date, sizeof date, &dp, &mp, &yp)) {
    puts("failed");
    return 1;
  }
}
```